# Can dandelion seeds be killed by drowning them in a bucket of water for 30 days?

Tags: weed-control, compost, weeds, dandelions, compost-tea

I used to put dandelions inside of a composting barrel with lawns clippings, unwanted junk mail (paper), etc...

However, the dandelions survived the composting process.

I would put the dandelions in the trash, except that I am trying to avoid making the landfills and garbage dumps larger. I would prefer to transform dead dandelions into compost or fertilizer or some other soil amendment.

If I put blooming dandelions in a bucket of cold water for 30 days will the seeds and roots die?

Comment: Maybe. But in an area where dandelions exist nearby, the wind will bring you lots of seeds.

Comment: Blooming ones? Remove the flowers from the rest of the plant and that immediately cuts the odds of them ever having enough resources to make seed. If you pull up the whole plant, it will put everything it's got into completing the seeding process for attached flowers. To be more through, grind up the flowers. Just don't wait until they are already past blooming. Other than the fact that I've never had any that wasn't terrible, if you modify your "soak in water process" to just blooms + sugar and yeast, you can make dandelion wine. Or you could simply boil the water to kill the plants & seeds.

Comment: By the way, you should be cautious about composting junk mail. It can have a huge variety of chemicals, plastics, etc.

Comment: Cut the flowers off and grind them underfoot, then cut the leaves off the root and compost them and the flower stems. Finally, leave the root in the sun for a week and it'll dry out. Burn it during your next cookout or let it mummify for the rest of the summer, then grind underfoot.